# Preventing dynamic PHP table display correctly

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have the following code to display a block of six products from a mysql database. 
It displays as two columns three rows and I get individual photos and correct page links in each of the six positions but the alt tags for the three products in column one are repeated in column 2. I cannot work out why. Any thoughts, and   ways to improve the code?

```
<?php
  // create query
  $query = "SELECT * FROM photogear WHERE qty != 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
  // execute query
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(MYSQL_ERROR);
?>
  <table>
    <?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $product2=$row['product'];
      $img2=$row['img'];
      $manuid2=$row['manuid'];
      $id2=$row['id'];
      $price=$row['price'];
    //GET MANUFACTURER FOR DISPLAY IN img title
      $manu_q = "SELECT * FROM manufacturers WHERE manuid = '$manuid2' ORDER BY name";
      $manu_r = mysql_query($manu_q) or die(mysql_error());
      $manu_info = mysql_fetch_array($manu_r);
      $name2=$manu_info['name'];
    ?> 
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php // for each product show photo with a link to product page 
          echo "<a href='product-".$row['id']."'><img src='".$row['img']."'alt='$name2,$product2 $price' title='$name2 $product2 &pound;$price' width='85'></a>";
         ?>
         <?php $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // make one record out.?>
       </td>  
       <td> 
         <?php // for each product show photo with a link to product page 
echo "<a href='product-".$row['id']."'><img src='".$row['img']."' alt='$name2, $product2 $price' title='$name2 $product2 &pound;$price' width='85'></a>";?>
      </td>
    </tr>
       <?php
} // End loops.
?>
</table>
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: That code is not easy on the eyes at all. Some tabs would make a world of difference.

Comment: alt='$name2, $product2 $price' title='$name2 $product2 &pound;$price' this line is duplicated in both the columns then alt tag will always same in 1 & 2 column

Comment: Hey I have a question
this line <?php $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // make one record out.?>
should be above echo statement ?

Comment: @NoPyGod thanks sorry yes still getting to grips with whether to tab or indent. I had indents but when posting in here i got an error message so set all to 4 as it stated.

Comment: Thanks @Sundar , so if I take out the duplicate line i get no alt tag. How do I ensure an alt tag is present in column 2

Comment: @DeDav when I move it above I get duplicate columns of photos as well as alt

Comment: if you are checking the alt string in jquery use $(id).prop('alt') or if you want relevant alt tag need to be present in 2nd column chnage the alt tag value

Comment: @Sundar .. I'm a beginner and that went right over my head :-( Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using $product2, $price try using $row['product'],$row['price'] in alt

Comment: Excellent, thanks so I did as suggested and I now have the correct product and price, but applying the same logic and changing $name2 with $manu_info['name'] doesn't rectify that so Now I have in column 2 the correct photo, correct link, correct price and correct product but duplicate name from column 1

Comment: After this line <?php  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // make one record out.?> Add this line mysql_fetch_assoc($manu_r); and try with $manu_info['name'] instead of $name2

Comment: out of interest is there any reason to include $product2=$row['product']; for $product2 if I need to use $row['product'] ?

Comment: Also when I have the ability to mark this as useful I will be back. Sorry I cant do that at the moment

Comment: $product2 is takes the same value and $row['product'] is takes the next value

Comment: ah ok thanks, so any idea why $manu_info['name'] still doesn't work?

Comment: If that worked this also must work may i know what you have added for $name2

Comment: I added  <?php $manu_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($manu_r);?> as you suggested and that's got rid of the duplicate name so now there's no name on column 2

Comment: Just try this but im not sure SELECT * FROM manufacturers WHERE manuid = '$manuid2' ORDER BY name

Answer (score 0):

Just try this but im not sure
Use this

```
     SELECT * FROM manufacturers WHERE manuid = '$row['manuid']' ORDER BY name
```

Instead of this

```
     SELECT * FROM manufacturers WHERE manuid = '$manuid2' ORDER BY name
```

After this

```
     $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

     Add this line
          $manu_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($manu_r);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help again...no that didn't work still no manufacturer name in column 2